# OPNQRYF and Open options ignored for shared open

Tags: cl, rpg

I am trying to work on a program and use the OPNQRYF command so that I only get certain records.  I keep getting a decimal data error in the RPG program like it does not have any data or something.  So, I just went to the basics so I can just add on to the program.

So I created the following simple CL.

```
PGM        PARM(&PSICU)                           
                                                  
DCL        VAR(&PSICU      ) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(   8)
DCL        VAR(&RECS) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(10 0)        
                                                  
OVRDBF     FILE(F0312) NBRRCDS(111) SHARE(*YES)   
OPNQRYF    FILE((F0312)) OPTION(*INP *UPD) FORMAT(*FILE) OPTIMIZE(*ALLIO) +          
    OPNID(*FILE) SEQONLY(*NO) TYPE(*PERM) KEYFLD((RUICUT) (RUICU) (RUDOCM) (RUAN8)) +  
    QRYSLT('(RUICU *EQ ' *CAT &PSICU *CAT ') & (RUPOST *EQ " ")')  

CPYFRMQRYF FROMOPNID(F0312) TOFILE(QTEMP/F0312) MBROPT(*ADD) CRTFILE(*YES) FMTOPT(*NOCHK)
RTVMBRD    FILE(QTEMP/F0312) NBRCURRCD(&RECS)             
IF         COND(&RECS *EQ 0) THEN(GOTO CMDLBL(EOJ))        
                                                   
 CALL       PGM(SMITHMIS/TSTOPNQRYR) PARM(&PSICU)  
EOJ:                                                   
   DLTF       FILE(QTEMP/F0312)                    
   CLOF       OPNID(F0312)                         
   MONMSG     MSGID(CPF0000 CPC0000 CPD0000)       
   DLTOVR     FILE(F0312)                          
   MONMSG     MSGID(CPF0000 CPC0000 CPD0000)       
 ENDPGM
```

Looking at my job log the OPNQRYF is getting 2 records (which is correct)

The RPG is simple like this:

```
FF0312   IF  E                    DISK                
FQSYSPRT O   F     132     OF     PRINTER             
C           *ENTRY    PLIST                           
C                     PARM           PSICU   8        
C*                                                    
C                     MOVELPSICU     @NM              
C                     CALL 'X0012'                    
C*                    ---- -------                    
C                     PARM           @NM    22        
C                     PARM           #NUMR  156       
C                     Z-ADD#NUMR     $WRK8   80       
C                     Z-ADD$WRK8     PSICU#  80       
C*                                                    
C           *INLR     DOWEQ'0'                        
C                     READ I0312                  99LR
C*                                                    
C*                                                    
C*    If negative document, make it positive          
C*                                                    
C           RUDOC     IFLT *ZERO                      
C                     MULT -1        RUDOC            
C                     ENDIF                           
C*                                                    
C           RUDOCM    IFLT *ZERO                      
C                     MULT -1        RUDOCM           
C                     ENDIF                           
C*                                            
C*    Determine if record should be processed.
C*                                            
C           *IN99     IFEQ '0'                
C           *INLR     ANDEQ'0'                
C           RUPOST    CABEQ'A'       END      
C*                    -----          ---      
C                     ENDIF                   
C*                                            
C           RUICU     IFNE PSICU#              
C                     GOTO END                 
C                     ENDIF                    
C*                                             
C           *INLR     CABEQ'1'       END       
C*                    -----          ---       
C                     ADD  1         CNT     50
C                     EXCPTDETL                
C           END       TAG                      
C                     ENDDO                
OQSYSPRT E      2         DETL             
O                         CNT   Z    5
```

When it gets to the RPG, there is nothing there.  When I look at the job log I see:

```
Member F0312 file F0312 in D81QUADTA opened.                         
   900 - CPYFRMQRYF FROMOPNID(F0312) TOFILE(QTEMP/F0312) MBROPT(*ADD)
  CRTFILE(*YES) FMTOPT(*NOCHK)                                       
Physical file F0312 created in library QTEMP.                        
Member F0312 added to file F0312 in QTEMP.                           
2 records copied from member F0312.                                  
  1000 - RTVMBRD FILE(QTEMP/F0312) NBRCURRCD(&RECS)                  
  1300 - CALL PGM(SMITHMIS/TSTOPNQRYR)          /* The CALL command  
  contains parameters */                                             
Open options ignored for shared open of member F0312.
```

Any ideas why it's ignoring my OPNQRYF?

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't ignore the query file, it doesn't get any record because after the `CPYFRMQRYF` command the open access path is positioned at the end of the file.
The *options ignored* message means the file is already opened with input and update (by `OPNQRYF`) and since the open is shared the RPG program can't open it input only

So you have to either

- close and reopen the query file
- close the query file and use the qtemp file as input.
- get rid of the `CPYFRMQRYF` and change the RPG program so that it does not en in error when there is no input